# Why a round shape in my excel become oval shape in another excel for another user/PC?

Tags: excel

I have created excel dashboard but while sharing with the management my different shapes in excel become different size for different user.

Comment: A round is just an oval with equidistant dimensions. The aspect ratio and/or pixel resolution is different between the two computers.

Comment: how to fix this? so that shape remain as it is on any computer?